# How can i search for a string in SQL which contains a colon?

Tags: sql, search

Is there a way I can search for a string in SQL which contains a colon?

Example:

I have values like `2009-09-17 05:00:00.000` and `2011-11-10 06:00:00.000` in the database. But I want all the values which have `05:` in them.

I tried the following SQL, but it gives me a blank result:

```
SELECT cast(narrative_date as datetime)
FROM P_MATTER_NARRATIVE
WHERE cast(narrative_date as datetime)
LIKE '%05:%';
```

Comment: If you're always looking for a specific hour, you can use the HOUR() function, much more reliable... I guess to do what you are trying to do you need to do an additional DATE_FORMAT() which you can then compare according to your criteria

Comment: On which database? Are you talking about strictly SQL as a language (database agnostic), or are you working with a specific database such as PostgreSQL, SQLite, MySQL, ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`HOUR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour) function in your query to get hours from your datetime column.

```
select narrative_date from P_MATTER_NARRATIVE 
where HOUR(narrative_date) = 5
```

Comment: Hi Harsh

Thanks for the reply. 
I executed the following query and it returned all the records having '05' in the hour field:

select narrative_date from P_MATTER_NARRATIVE where DATEPART(hh,narrative_date) = 05 

This worked.